# Ionic2 won't disable form control

Tags: angular, ionic2

Try the following HTML:

```
<ion-content class="home">

  <ion-list>
    <form [formGroup]="consoleTypeForm">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Gaming</ion-label>
        <ion-select FormControlName="consoleType" (ionChange)="printSV($event)">
          <ion-option value="nes">NES</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="n64">Nintendo64</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="ps">PlayStation</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="genesis">Sega Genesis</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="saturn">Sega Saturn</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="snes">SNES</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Business Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="myConsole" type="text"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </form>
</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

With the following controller class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  consoleTypeForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(public nav: NavController,
              public menu: MenuController,
              public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.consoleTypeForm = formBuilder.group({
      consoleType: ['', Validators.required],
      myConsole: ['']
    });
  }

  printSV(value)
  {
    const ctrl = this.consoleTypeForm.controls['consoleType'];
    const ctrlToBeDisabled = this.consoleTypeForm.controls['myConsole'];

    ctrlToBeDisabled.enable(false);
    ctrlToBeDisabled.disable({ onlySelf: true });
    ctrlToBeDisabled.disable(true);
    ctrlToBeDisabled.disable();
  }
}
```

None of the options to disable 'myConsole' work.  Can someone please point out the mistake?  or, is this a big?

Ionic Framework version: 2.0.0-rc.2,
Ionic CLI version:2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version:2.1.0-beta.1

Answer (score 0):

I haven't executed the code, but from reading I point out at least 2 things:

`FormControlName="consoleType"` should read `formControlName="consoleType"`

I'd place creating the FormGroup into `ionViewDidLoad()` life-cycle method:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.consoleTypeForm = formBuilder.group({
    consoleType: ['', Validators.required],
    myConsole: ['']
  });
}
```

I don't know whether it's causing problems doing it in the constructor, but I've read example code and for me it's working.

The type definition of the `AbstractControl` has following method to disable a control:

```
/**
 * Disables the control. This means the control will be exempt from validation checks and
 * excluded from the aggregate value of any parent. Its status is `DISABLED`.
 *
 * If the control has children, all children will be disabled to maintain the model.
 */
disable({onlySelf, emitEvent}?: {
    onlySelf?: boolean;
    emitEvent?: boolean;
}): void;
```

From that I'd try to disable with:

```
control.disable();
```

or

```
control.disable({onlySelf: true});
```

Tell me if it helped and in case create a Plunkr so we can play around with your code.